# Cannot convert Bukkit Scoreboard score to String

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So here's my Bukkit plugin code

```
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.*;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
//import org.bukkit.*;

public class GetScore extends JavaPlugin{


@Override
public void onEnable() {
    // TODO Insert logic to be performed when the plugin is enabled
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    // TODO Insert logic to be performed when the plugin is disabled
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("getscore")) { // If the player typed /basic then do the following...
        // doSomething
        ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
        Scoreboard board = manager.getMainScoreboard();
        //Scoreboard sb = new Scoreboard();
        Objective objective = board.getObjective("Kill");
        Score score = objective.getScore("John");
        //sender.sendMessage(score.toString());
        sender.sendMessage(score.toString());
        return true;
    } //If this has happened the function will return true. 
        // If this hasn't happened the value of false will be returned.
    return false; 
}
}
```

The thing is plugin compiles without errors,but when i type /getscore I get this:
org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R4.scoreboard.CraftScore@16f690c
Of course this is not what I wanted,It should output John's score on objective Kill.Which is 38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `toString()` is as follows:
`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`

You'll have to provide an override for `Score`'s toString() method and in there, return the appropriate value.

Comment: and what do you mean by return the appropriate value?

Comment: That completely depends on what `Score` is. After a Google search, it appears replacing the line `sender.sendMessage(score.toString());` by `sender.sendMessage(Integer.toString(score.getScore()));` will fix your problem.

Comment: I don't get it,getScore() will just return an null,because I didn't give it information to look on which objective and which player

Comment: `getScore()` is a method in the `Score` interface which you should invoke on the variable named `score`, that you retrieve through `objective.getScore("John")`. As you can see (https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/scoreboard/Score.html#getScore()), `getScore()` returns `int`, which can not possibly be null.

Comment: Thanks and there was no need to add override,again thanks I asked this in bukkit forums 2 times,they removed 2 of them before i got any reply and told me it was spam,I wrote it in spigot forums,they helped me to correct some of my code and you did the last piece

Answer (score 0):

To get a players Score in bukkit, you should call [getScore()](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/scoreboard/Score.html#getScore()) on the Score object you have. This will return an int containing the score the player have.

Before you call getScore() you should verify you have a Score object and that it isn't null.

```java
ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
Scoreboard board = manager.getMainScoreboard();
Objective objective = board.getObjective("Kill");
Score score = objective.getScore("John");
int playerKills;
if(score == null) { // John didn't make any kills, and hasn't entered the scoeboard yet
    playerKills = 0;
} else {
    playerKills = score.getScore();
}
sender.sendMessage("Your kills: " + String.valueOf(score));
```

A large part of the above code is copied from your question, and only the last few lines have been adjusted. Before running the code, make sure the kills objective exists by running `/scoreboard objectives add Kills totalKillCount` or using your own code to make the objective from code.